# Two ways JOIN in MySql

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to build a query with 4 different tables:

- Users_Licences
- Licences
- Products
- Request

The `Users` have multiple `Licences`, stored in `Users_Licences`. `Products` have multiple `Requests` and in the `Request` table you have target licence where in the `Products` table you have `source_licence`.

I want to list all the requests that have target licences and source licences (via `Products`) that the specified user has in his `Users_Licences` table.

Complicated but this is where I'm at this point (not working):

```
SELECT 
    Request.id AS offer_id, Request.product_id, 
    Request.licence_id AS target_licence_id, 
    Request.trans_price, Products.source_licence_id    
FROM 
    Request    
JOIN 
    Products ON Request.product_id = Products.id    
JOIN 
    Licences ON Products.source_licence_id = Licences.id    
JOIN 
    Licences ON Request.licence_id = Licences.id    
JOIN 
    Users_Licences ON Licences.id = Users_Licences.licence_id    
WHERE 
    Users_Licences.user_id = '$user_id'    
GROUP BY 
    Request.id    
ORDER BY 
    Request.trans_price DESC
```

Could you help me out? If I delete the line

```
JOIN Licences ON Products.source_licence_id = Licences.id
```

it works but I have part of my result...Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use different alias name wheh you use the table more than a time

```
SELECT Request.id AS offer_id, Request.product_id, Request.licence_id AS target_licence_id, Request.trans_price 
, Products.source_licence_id     
FROM Request     
JOIN Products ON Request.product_id = Products.id     
JOIN Licences as l1 ON Products.source_licence_id = l1.id     
JOIN Licences as l2 ON Request.licence_id = l2.id     
JOIN Users_Licences ON l2.id = Users_Licences.licence_id     
WHERE Users_Licences.user_id='$user_id'     
GROUP BY Request.id     
ORDER BY Request.trans_price DESC
```

Comment: Excellent! I forgot about that... The code you provided didn't work directly, I had to use alias for Users_Licences too.. But thanks a lot for this.